# How can we share fosuserbundle session (symfony) with media wiki?

Tags: symfony, mediawiki, fosuserbundle

How to configure media `wiki` to use `fosuserbundle` session from Symfony.

i try this https://github.com/symcode/mediawiki_symfony_bridge but giving me error "Exception encountered, of type "`InvalidArgumentException`"

Comment: That extension is way outdated. You should create a [session provider](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:SessionManager_and_AuthManager#SessionProvider).

Comment: How can i create session provider, help me to create this.